# How to setup bind9 as simple name resolver?

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

### What?

I want to setup my own dns resolver. For everything that is not in 192.168.178.0/24 forward it to google dns (8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4 as fallback). So I just want to setup the nameserver of every host to lets say ``192.168.178.10` and that should be everything I need.
How can I setup bind9 doing this?

### Why?

My Fritz!Box is just not resolving most of the hostnames in my network. And I'm pretty sick of it - I tried troubleshooting it but the web interface is not very helpfull. It's not possible to telnet into it anymore because of firmware restrictions.

Comment: Suggest the [Ubuntu Server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns.html) as a "how to" reference.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up `bind9` is The Hard Way. Ubuntu (you are running Ubuntu, right?) comes with `dnsmasq`, a simple DNS server that respects `/etc/hosts`. Read `man dnsmasq`, then you can distribute `192.168.178.10` (DNS server address) manually or via DHCP .